# Bootstrap 4 tether placements

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4, tether

Bootstrap 4 using tether.js as for positions, however it only support 4 position, "top" "right" "bottom" "left", how can I extend to more options which tether support 12 of them? example "top left" or "top right"

Comment: how do you use it on bootstrap? <i class="test" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="top right" data-title="" data-tip="test"></i> this returns an error.

Comment: Note that Bootstrap is [moving away from Tether](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/22444), with the new implementation. I [raised your issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/22444#issuecomment-296376275) in the relative PR.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the bootstrap only accepts the [4 placement options](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/tooltips/#options) - check the open [github issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17759).

> Currently bootstrap only supports 4 placement options, while tether supports 12.

So, using the bootstraps tooltip won't help you, but you can always use [tether.js](https://github.com/HubSpot/tether) or it's [tooltip.js](https://github.com/HubSpot/tooltip).

Here's an example using `tooltip.js`:

```js
new Tooltip({
  target: document.getElementById('foobar'),
  position: 'right middle',
  content: '<div id="foo">bar</div>',
});
```

```css
#foo{
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether-tooltip/1.2.0/css/tooltip-theme-arrows.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.2/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether-drop/1.4.2/js/drop.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether-tooltip/1.2.0/js/tooltip.min.js"></script>

<a href=# id="foobar">I'm a link!</a>
```

Also here's [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0xaxv377/)